# Getting results for only partial inputs for queries using Spring Boot Hibernate Criteria API PostGRES

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am having a problem with retrieving results using the full value of strings being passed to a REST endpoint.

If I pass the full 6 character string for the value "communityNo", I get an empty Json array back.
If I pass 1-3 of the first 6 characters for communityNo, then I get tons of records back.

1. REST endpt url : http://localhost:8080/web-portal/api/aw501?stateId=2&communityNo=200
2. criteria api specifications

```
public static Specification<Aw501> findAllByStateId(String stateId){
       return new Specification <Aw501>(){
           public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Aw501> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
               return cb.like(root.get(Aw501_.stateId),   stateId + "%"); //MDB
           }

       } ;
   }


   public static Specification<Aw501> findAllByCommunityNo(String communityNo){
       return new Specification <Aw501>(){
           public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Aw501> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
               return cb.like(root.get(Aw501_.communityNo),  communityNo + "%"); //MDB
           }       

       } ;
   }

}
```

3. repository interface

```
package pivot.fema.dhs.gov.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import pivot.fema.dhs.gov.domain.report.Aw501;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the Claims entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface Aw501Repository
        extends JpaRepository<Aw501, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Aw501> {
}
```

4. service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Aw501Service {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Aw501Service.class);


    private final Aw501Repository aw501Repository;

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    private ReportSessionParameters reportSessionParameters;


    @Inject
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    private ApplicationProperties.Performance performance;


    public Aw501Service(Aw501Repository aw501Repository,
                        CacheManager cacheManager){
                            this.aw501Repository = aw501Repository;
                            this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }



    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Aw501DTO>  getAw501Reports(Integer pageNumber, 
                                           Integer pageSize, 
                                           String  sortBy, 
                                           String  sortOrder,
                                           String stateId, 
                                           String communityNo){

        boolean flagStateId = StringUtils.isNotBlank(stateId) ;
        boolean flagCommunityNo = StringUtils.isNotBlank(communityNo) ;


        if(flagStateId){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  flag input for flagStateId :" +  true + "****");
        }else{

        }


        if(flagCommunityNo){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  flag input for flagCommunityNo :" +  true + "****");
        }else{

        }




        Specifications<Aw501> predicates = null ;




       if(flagStateId && flagCommunityNo){
            predicates =  Specifications.where(Aw501Spec.findAllByStateId(stateId)) ;
            predicates = predicates.and(Specifications.where(Aw501Spec.findAllByCommunityNo(communityNo)));
        }

        if( flagStateId && flagCommunityNo){
            if(flagStateId){
                log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (flagStateId && flagCommunityNo):" +  true + "****  predicates = " + predicates.toString());
            }else{

            }
        }




        if(flagStateId && !flagCommunityNo){
            predicates =  Specifications.where(Aw501Spec.findAllByStateId(stateId)) ;
        }

        if(flagStateId && !flagCommunityNo){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (flagStateId && !flagCommunityNo):" +  true + "****  predicates = " + predicates.toString());
        }else{

        }


        if( !flagStateId && flagCommunityNo){
            predicates = Specifications.where(Aw501Spec.findAllByCommunityNo(communityNo)) ;
        }

        if(!flagStateId && flagCommunityNo ){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (!flagStateId && flagCommunityNo):" +  true + "****  predicates = " + predicates.toString());
        }else{

        }

        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(1,25);

        if(pageRequest  != null ){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (pageRequest): pageRequest is not null"  + "****  pageNumber = " +  pageRequest.toString() + " pageOffset : " + "" );
        }else{
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (pageRequest): pageRequest is  null"  + "****  " );
        }

        Page<Aw501DTO> foobar = aw501Repository
                .findAll(predicates,pageRequest)
                .map(Aw501DTO::new);


        if(foobar  != null ){
            log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (foobar): foobaris not null"  + "****  foobar = " +  foobar.hasContent() +  " pageOffset : " + "" );
        }else{
                log.info("****Aw501Service.java  (foobar): pageRequest is  null"  + "****  " );
        }

        return foobar ;
    }//end getAw501Reports

}
```

5. RestController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Aw501Resource{


    Page<Aw501DTO> page = new PageImpl<Aw501DTO>(Collections.<Aw501DTO>emptyList());

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Aw501Resource.class);

    private final Aw501Repository aw501Repository;

    private final Aw501Service aw501Service;

    private final ReportSessionParameters reportSessionParameters;



    public Aw501Resource(Aw501Repository aw501Repository,
                         Aw501Service aw501Service,
                         ReportSessionParameters reportSessionParameters) {

        this.aw501Repository = aw501Repository;
        this.aw501Service = aw501Service;
        this.reportSessionParameters = reportSessionParameters;
    }


    /*
        A page is a sublist of a list of objects.  It allows  gain 
        information about the about the posistion of it in 
        th e containing entire list. 
    */

    @GetMapping("/aw501")

    public  Page<Aw501DTO> getAw501(@RequestParam(name = "stateId", required = false) String stateId,
    @RequestParam(name = "communityNo", required = false) String communityNo,
    @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", required = false) String sortBy,
    @RequestParam(name = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder,
    @RequestParam(name = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
    @RequestParam(name = "pageNumber", required = false) Integer pageNumber){


        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(stateId)){
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for stateId :" +  stateId  + "****");
            stateId = stateId.trim() ;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(communityNo)){
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for communityNo :" +  communityNo  + "****");
            communityNo = communityNo.trim() ;
        }


        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sortBy)){
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for sortBy :" +  sortBy  + "****");
            sortBy =  sortBy.trim() ;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(sortOrder)){
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for sortOrder :" +  sortOrder  + "****");
            sortOrder =  sortOrder.trim() ;
        }



        if (pageNumber != null && pageNumber.compareTo(0) > 0){
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for pageNumber :" +  pageNumber.toString()  + "****");
            pageNumber-- ;
            log.info("****Aw501Resource.java  input for pageNumber-- :" +  pageNumber.toString()  + "****");
        }

        return aw501Service.getAw501Reports(pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder, stateId,communityNo);
    }

    @GetMapping("/foobar")
    public Map<String,String> foobar(@RequestParam(name = "stateId", required = false) String stateId,
    @RequestParam(name = "communityNo", required = false) String communityNo,
    @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", required = false) String sortBy,
    @RequestParam(name = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder,
    @RequestParam(name = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
    @RequestParam(name = "pageNumber", required = false) Integer pageNumber){
        Map<String , String> map = new HashMap<String,String>() ;
        map.put("stateId","51") ;
        map.put("sortBy","DESC");
        map.put("pageSize","25");
        map.put("pageNumber","100");
        return map ;
    }


}
```

Any help you guys could provide would be extremely appreciated!!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: It is because of this statement `stateId + "%"`

Comment: No, that's not the reason.  the wild card predicate actually works for all cases.  I solved the issue a while back, but forgot  to post the solution here.   Basically the issue was within Aw501Service.java  Thanks for the effort tho!!! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Aw501Service.java

```
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(1,25);
```

The reason why I was getting results with only partial inputs that matched the predicate wild card in the criteria code but nothing when the input was an exact match;  was that the PageRequest object uses an array internally to store retrieved objects.  If there is only one object returned...as would be expected from an exact match within the context of my application....then accessing that array at index [1] will naturally return "nothing".   I correct the issue via the simple modification to the aforementioned line of code to :

```
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0,25);
```